# Showing how much memory a data structure is using

Tags: memory, size, raku

I have a huge hash containing about 10 years worth of daily statistical data. Is there is a way in Perl 6 to determine how much real memory (in bytes) this hash is using (e.g. `showMemoryUsed(%myBigHash)`). Even if `%myBigHash` is empty, it is not zero bytes because of the memory used and the Perl 6 implementation of the hash data type. This info will tell me if I need to re-implement my codes or periodically write out to file to alleviate RAM shortage (my program is running on a virtualized Linux with 2G RAM).

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alas, we don't have a thing like that in Rakudo Perl 6 yet.  The only thing I can recommend, is using the `Telemetry` module:

```
use Telemetry;
my $before = T<max-rss>;
my %h = ...; # initialize hash
say "Memory usage grew { T<max-rss> - $before } KB";
```

Check out the Telemetry documentation for more information: https://docs.raku.org/type/Telemetry

Comment: Thank you Elizabeth Mattijsen for your clarification !! I will check out Telemetry module.